# Injecting JS file into Windows 10 UAP webview

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

How can I inject entire JS file from app resources into the HTML page in Windows 10 app webview?

I tried on Webview `NavigationCompleted` load the javascript file from app resources and inject it using:

```
webview.InvokeScriptAsync ("eva", jsDataLoadedFromResources)
```

It does not seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean "It does not seem to work."? Could you please share more details? A [mcve] would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject Javascript in the [WebView.DOMContentLoaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.domcontentloaded.aspx) event.

For example:

```
private async void WebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    await this.WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "var script = document.createElement('script');script.innerHTML = 'var el = document.createElement(\"div\");el.innerHTML=\"My injected content\";document.body.appendChild(el);';document.body.appendChild(script);" });
}
```

I have created a tag `script` and then injected the content of the script, before adding it at the end of the body element.